# Strange memory allocation in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, garbage-collection

After loading 20 images from 1 code, task manager in android phone displays 4mb. From 2nd code it displays 9mb.

BUT, in both cases Android Studio displays the same 2.9mb allocated 1.8mb free even after calling Garbage Collector. Why does it happen? And which one is the real heap?

1 code:

```
img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.img);
```

2 code:

```
img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.img);
img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img,
            (int)(img.getWidth() * scale), (int)(img.getHeight() * scale), false);
```

PS: scale variable == 1

Answer (score 0):

Try to change second code to:

```
img1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.img);
img2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img1,
            (int)(img1.getWidth() * scale), (int)(img1.getHeight() * scale), false);
img1.recycle();
```

So, you can try to detect memory consumpsion programaticaly

```
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
```